# Replacing a for loop with an STL algorithm while allowing parallelism

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, atomic, stl-algorithm

I have this method :

```
void A::overlapOut(int pos)
{
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {
        out[pos+j] += local_arr[j] / scalingFactor;
    }
}
```

I would like to do refactor it using an STL algorithm like `std::transform`, mainly for code consistency. 
I have about five other methods which are variations on the theme, that I have been able to refactor using `std::transform` or `std::copy`, like this :

```
void A::nonOverlapOut(int pos)
{
    auto normalize = [&] (double x) { return x / otherScalingFactor; };
    std::transform(local_arr, local_arr + size, out + pos, normalize);
}
```

However, here the main difference lies in the `+=`. All of my others function don't overlap, and don't use the previous value in `data[i]` so parallel calls can be made, but this one needs to do `data[i] += stuff`, instead of `data[i] = stuff`, and `data[i]` might be accessed by other threads who would also do `+=`.

So, what would be the best, C++11-ic way to do this ? I thought about using `std::atomic<double>` instead of `double` for my arrays, but would it slow down the calculations in the places where I don't need atomic access ?

Comment: If you have multiple threads doing += to the same location, you need to sync them anyway, so the original code cannot remain as is.

Comment: If multiple threads can potentially do `data[i] = stuff` you have a data race there as well as the `data[i] += stuff` case (simply writing to a `double` may not be inherently atomic). I would strongly suggest trying `std::atomic` and testing to see if there is a problematic performance impact.

Comment: Yes, my questions is maybe two questions into one: how to make += with stl algorithm, and how to put some thread safety in that code in the less performance-reducing way.

@BoBTFish : for the `data[i] = stuff`, every thread would call on a different set of values, like T1 would call for i between 0 and 255, thread 2 would call for i between 256 and 511...

Comment: Synchronisation primitives can be emulated using std::atomic<bool> and active wait. It has it's limits but often better then mutex or some.

Answer (score 0):

`std::transform` can take *two* input ranges, and the output iterator may be the same as the inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    double local_arr[] = {9.0, 8.0, 5.0, 4.0, 5.0};
    double out[] = {12.0, 24.0, 36.0, 48.0, 60.0, 72.0, 84.0};
    auto scalingFactor = 7.0;

    size_t size = 5;
    size_t pos = 1;

    std::transform(local_arr, local_arr + size, out + pos, out + pos,
                    [=](double a, double b) { return a / scalingFactor + b; });

    for (auto v : out) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that this does a `data[i] = data[i] + stuff` instead of `data[i] += stuff`. So making `data[i]` an array of `std::atomic<double>` with this code will not result in a single atomic instruction.

But in your case, different threads write to disjoint parts of the array, so there are no conflicts (§1.10/4), thus no data races (§1.10/21), and thus thread-safe without needing atomics or locks.